# Bash: Check if ONE and ONLY ONE of several variables equals

Tags: bash

I'm trying to properly format "and" when it comes to reading time. I'd like to try to figure out how to only echo "and" before the last value (whether it be Hours, Minutes, or Seconds) and only if there's more than one value (need two values, ie: 2 Days, and 5 minutes, or 2 Days, 12 hours, and 5 minutes)

I don't know the proper syntax to say, if ONLY one of the values, H, M, and S is greater than 0, then $DAnd="and ".
This would be repeated for hours as well, so if ONLY of the values, M and S is greater than 0, then "$HAnd="and ".
For minutes, it's easy, as it's only checking to see if S is greater than 0.

How does one achieve this without making a large mess of code?

My current script:

```
#!/bin/bash
TIME1="08/15/2018 10:30:41"
TIME2="08/30/2018 8:34:40"
SEC1=`date +%s -d "${TIME1}"`
SEC2=`date +%s -d "${TIME2}"`
DIFF=`expr ${SEC2} - ${SEC1}`
CONVERTTIME()
{
  local T=$1
  local D=$((T/60/60/24))
  local H=$((T/60/60%24))
  local M=$((T/60%60))
  local S=$((T%60))
  if [[ $D > 0 ]]; then
    [[ ($H = 0 || $M = 0 || $S = 0) && ($H = 0 && $M = 0 && $S = 0) ]] && DComma="" || DComma=","
    #The problem
    [[ ($H > 0 || $M > 0 || $S > 0) && ($H = 0 || $M = 0 || $S = 0) ]] && DAnd="" || DAnd="and "
    [[ $D = 1 ]] && echo -n "$D day$DComma " || echo -n "$D days$DComma $DAnd"

  fi
  if [[ $H > 0 ]]; then
    [[ ($M = 0 || $S = 0) && ($M = 0 && $S = 0) ]] && HComma="" || HComma=","
    #The problem
    [[ ($M > 0 || $S > 0) && ($M = 0 || $S = 0) ]] && HAnd="" || HAnd="and "
    [[ $H = 1 ]] && echo -n "$H hour$HComma $HAnd" || echo -n "$H hours$HComma $HAnd"
  fi
  if [[ $M > 0 ]]; then
    [[ $S = 0 ]] && MComma="" || MComma=", and "
    [[ $M = 1 ]] && echo -n "$M minute$MComma" || echo -n "$M minutes$MComma"
  fi
  if [[ $S > 0 ]]; then
    [[ $S = 0 ]] && echo -n "$S second" || echo -n "$S seconds"
  fi
  # If no difference in time:
  [[ $D = 0 && $H = 0 && $M = 0 && $S = 0 ]] && echo -n "0 seconds"
  echo
}
echo
echo "TIME DIFFERENCE: $(CONVERTTIME $DIFF)"
echo
```

Comment: I recommend you install the [dateutils](http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/) package so you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @Wildcard, how would you do that with `dateutils`? Off the top of the man page, I can't see how to get that output format.

Comment: @ilkkachu, it was a general comment; I don't think `dateutils` can handle *specifically* the use case of including the "and" string before the final unit, and leaving out the units that are 0.  But it can easily compute the diff between two dates (provided in any format you like) and print the output according to any static format string you like.  So not an answer to this precise use case, but hopefully useful for future readers anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd write that as

```
seconds2text() {     
    local diff=$1
    local words=()
    if (( diff == 0 )); then
        words=("0 seconds")
    else
        local s=$((diff % 60))
        local m=$((diff / 60 % 60))
        local h=$((diff / 60 / 60 % 24))
        local d=$((diff / 60 / 60 / 24))

        (( d > 0 )) && { unit=day;    (( d > 1 )) && unit+=s; words+=("$d $unit"); };
        (( h > 0 )) && { unit=hour;   (( h > 1 )) && unit+=s; words+=("$h $unit"); }
        (( m > 0 )) && { unit=minute; (( m > 1 )) && unit+=s; words+=("$m $unit"); }
        (( s > 0 )) && { unit=second; (( s > 1 )) && unit+=s; words+=("$s $unit"); }
        (( ${#words[@]} > 1 )) && words[-1]="and ${words[-1]}"
    fi
    local IFS=,
    local text="${words[*]}"
    text=${text/,and/ and}
    echo "${text//,/, }"
}
```

and then

```
$ for d in 0 1 61 3600 3601 3660 3661 86400 86401 86460 86461 90000 90001 90060 90061 180122; do seconds2text $d; done
0 seconds
1 second
1 minute and 1 second
1 hour
1 hour and 1 second
1 hour and 1 minute
1 hour, 1 minute and 1 second
1 day
1 day and 1 second
1 day and 1 minute
1 day, 1 minute and 1 second
1 day and 1 hour
1 day, 1 hour and 1 second
1 day, 1 hour and 1 minute
1 day, 1 hour, 1 minute and 1 second
2 days, 2 hours, 2 minutes and 2 seconds
```

Notes:

- `[[ $x > 0 ]]` and `[[ $x = 0 ]]` are doing *string* comparison, not *numeric* comparison. Use `((x > 0))` and `((x == 0))` instead (and note that the `$` is not required there).
- get out of the habit of using ALLCAPS variables. Leave those for the shell. One day you'll write `PATH=something` and then wonder why your script is broken.

Comment: in zsh, you could write `path=something` and still wonder why the script broke.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
t1=${1?first date please}
t2=${2?second date please}

zmodload zsh/datetime
strftime -rst1 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S' "$t1" || exit
strftime -rst2 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S' "$t2" || exit

t=$((t2 - t1))
if ((t)) {
  and=' and' out= plural=s
  for unit duration (
    second 60
    minute 60
    hour   24
    day    7
    week   t+1
  ) {
    ((n = t % duration))
    ((t /= duration))
    ((n > 0)) && out="$and $n $unit${plural: n<2}$out" and=,
    ((t)) || break
  }
  out=${out#?* }
} else {
  out=now
}
echo "$out"
```

Then:

```
./that-script "08/15/2018 10:30:41" "08/30/2018 8:34:40"
2 weeks, 22 hours, 3 minutes and 59 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

How about combining the `date` command with a `sed` script  )for a date / time difference less than a year)? Try

```
date +"%j d, %H h, %M m, %S s" -d@$(((d-90000))) | sed -r 's/, 0*00 .//g; s/365 d,* *//; s/ ([0-9]{2} [dhms])$/ and \1/; s/(^| )0+/\1/g; s/^$/0 s/; s/([02-9] [dhms])/\1s/g; s/ d(s|,|$)/ day\1/; s/ h/ hour/; s/ m/ minute/; s/ s/ second/'
```

Stealing the test loop from glenn jackman's post:

```
for DIFF in 0 1 61 3600 3601 3660 3661 86400 86401 86460 86461 90000 90001 90060 90061 180122
  do date +"%j d, %H h, %M m, %S s" -d@$(((DIFF-90000))) |
sed -r '
s/, 0*00 .//g
s/365 d,* *//
s/ ([0-9]{2} [dhms])$/ and \1/
s/(^| )0+/\1/g
s/^$/0 s/
s/([02-9] [dhms])/\1s/g
s/ d(s|,|$)/ day\1/
s/ h/ hour/
s/ m/ minute/
s/ s/ second/
'; done
0 seconds
1 second
1 minute, and 1 second
1 hour
1 hour, and 1 second
1 hour, and 1 minute
1 hour, 1 minute, and 1 second
1 day
1 day, and 1 second
1 day, and 1 minute
1 day, 1 minute, and 1 second
1 day, and 1 hour
1 day, 1 hour, and 1 second
1 day, 1 hour, and 1 minute
1 day, 1 hour, 1 minute, and 1 second
2 days, 2 hours, 2 minutes, and 2 seconds
```

(I know it will fail to add the plural `s` at any number ending in 1, e.g. 11, 21 etc...)